# Participants in chat have "truncated" names

Tags: feature-request, chat, design

When in chat the list of participants (on the left hand side) has the bottom of the name truncated.

Firefox 38.0.5, Windows.

Changing the page zoom level does not fix it.

[image]

Please can we allow more room so that the name is not truncated.

Comment: Have you set a minimum font size? (about:preferences#content then choose Advanced...)

Comment: @RobertLongson Good call. Yep, that was it. I would close the question ... but it might be useful for someone else ...

Comment: Please don't close it.  "Undo your minimum font size" is a workaround, but you presumably set that minimum size for a good reason (and undoing it affects all sites, not just SE).  I hope we can make this better for those who can't see the small default font.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Don't worry, I won't close it - it's earning me rep;) And you are right the minimum font size I had set worked how I liked it for pretty much every other site I use (except for chat). It would be good if it was "fixed". I will update the question to make it a feature request.

Comment: Install the add-on in the answer to make it per-site.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the info about the add-on; I'll have a look.  David, I agree with the suggestion (in comments on the answer) to leave this question as-is and make a separate feature-request.  The answer here is valid for the question you asked (it offers a workaround); it wouldn't be a valid answer for a feature request.  Please don't invalidate an upvoted answer with an edit.

Comment: @MonicaCellio OK I will ask a new question.

Comment: @MonicaCellio [Setting a minimum font size breaks chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258779)

Comment: @MonicaCellio [Setting a minimum font size breaks chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258779)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a minimum font size set. That means the text is bigger than it otherwise would be.

To reset it enter about:preferences#content in the address bar, or alternatively select Preferences under the Firefox menu on Mac and choose Content (or Options via the Tools menu on Windows).

The press the Advanced... button and you should see a dialogue box with minimum font size option. Ensure that says None e.g.

[image: Minimum font size]

There is a Firefox add on that allows the [minimum font size to be set on a per-domain basis](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/minimum-font-size-per-domain/). Using that would allow you to keep the minimum font size on all other domains where it might be useful to you.

Comment: You've identified the cause of the problem, but I don't think "undo that minimum size, that you probably had a good reason to set, and effect *every page you visit* is a great workaround.  I have this problem too and it hinders my use of chat, but I can't see the tiny size that's used by default.  I hope the designers will consider easing up on that somehow, or allowing more room for a larger user-chosen size to fit, or something.  (I don't know what's possible here, but wonder if there's a way to make the "container" bigger than the small font requires, to allow room for a larger font.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've added some information about a per-domain minimum font-size add-on which may help with the first issue in your comment.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the add-on, I will give it a go. However I suspect that the issue will affect other browsers as well. Updating my question to make it a feature request.

Comment: @DavidPostill I think asking a new question is a better way to go. Feel free to refer to this question/answer in it.

Comment: [Setting a minimum font size breaks chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258779)

Comment: The addon is not able to reduce font size below the default value set by Firefox settings. So to use it I have to set minimum font size in firefox to off, which "breaks" every other website ... :/