# Setting a minimum font size breaks chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, design, accessibility

Setting a minimum font size breaks chat.

See [Participants in chat have "truncated" names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258770/participants-in-chat-have-truncated-names) for the backgound.

As pointed out by [Robert Longson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/188189/robert-longson) it was caused by specifying a minumum font size in my browser.

Undoing this fixed the issue with chat (which is the only place I noticed a problem).

However, it has the side effect of affecting **every** web site I visit.

I had the minimum size set because the default font was too small for me to comfortably read - my age is catching up on me. I'm sure this will be similar for other users with "accessibilty" issues as well.

Can we change the page design to work correctly when minimim fonts sizes are set?

Notes:

1. It probably affects other browsers as well...
2. It only affects chat entries that are 1 or 2 lines (3+ line chat entries are fine).
3. The singe line entries reduce the avatar size to fit in one line.